# Call Rest API from Swift3

Tags: swift, ibm-mobilefirst

I trying to send a `POST` request in swift for example :

```
url = "http://localhost:9080/mfp/api/az/v1/token"
```

Headers :

```
Authorization = "Basic UGlua0NhclBhc3NlbmdlcjoxMjM0"
Content-Type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

Body :

```
grant_type = client_credentials
scope = RegisteredClient messages.write push.application.com.XXX
```

What's simple way to do it ?

I've tried by use IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation SDK, it's return error `"Can't not connect to server"`,but i'm sure that the connect still good... Here's my code :

```
let urlString = "http://localhost:9080/mfp/api/az/v1/token"
    let url1 = URL(string: urlString)
    let request1 = WLResourceRequest(url: url1! as URL, method: WLHttpMethodPost)!
    request1.addHeaderValue("Basic UGlua0NhclBhc3NlbmdlcjoxMjM0" as NSObject, forName: "Authorization")
    request1.addHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded" as NSObject, forName: "Content-Type")
    request1.send(withBody: "{\"grant_type\":\"client_credentials\",\"scope\":\"RegisteredClient messages.write push.application.com.XXX\"}", completionHandler: { (response, error) in
        if error == nil {
            print("Response : ")
            print(response)
        } else {
            print("Error : ")
            print(error)
        }
    })
```

Comment: SO is not a free coding website. Show some research effort, including what you have tried so far and what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alamofire as ZassX suggested or you can use URLSession.

I have some code as an example:

```
func postRequest(toUrl url: String, accessKey: String?, completion: @escaping(Data?, HTTPURLResponse?, Error?, AnyObject?) -> Void){
        let requestUrl = NSURL(string: url)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestUrl! as URL)
        if accessKey != nil {
            request.setValue("\(accessKey!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        }

        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        request.httpBody = yourBody

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data,response,error) in

            if let content = data{
                do{
                    let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    completion(data as Data?, response as? HTTPURLResponse, error, myJSON)
                }
                catch{
                    print("JSON ERROR")
                }
            }else{
                completion(data as Data?, response as? HTTPURLResponse, error, nil)
            }

        }).resume()
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `mutableContainers` when generating a JSON in `Swift`, since it has no effect. You also have no need for the optional castings for data and response. Moreover, judging from the fact that the "POST" request is not using `JSON` format, its return value most probably won't be in `JSON` format either.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't manually manage the security token when you're using the MobileFirst SDK, it's handled automatically.

Next, `WLResourceRequest()` takes a URL that is relative to the MobileFirst server URL (http://localhost:9080/mfp, in your case). You can see that "base" URL in your `mfpclient.plist` file.

Your code will then look something like

```
let request = WLResourceRequest(
    URL: NSURL(string: "/adapters/MyAdapter/myResource"),
    method: WLHttpMethodGet
)
```

See https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/resource-request/ios/